# Ruby Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I'm totally new at Rails and I've started to work on my first app and I've having a problem I cannot solve.

Basically I'm tracking rental properties, so I have controllers and models for Homes, Tenants, Leases, Vendors, Repairs, etc. I've been able to setup all of them and create new records, update, edit, etc, from webforms EXCEPT for one called TENANTS.

Since I couldn't get the app the save records from the web form - I went over to Rails console and have the same problem. I cannot save to the database from the console.

Example of what I did in console to create a new "Tenant" record

```
 tenant = Tenant.new
=> #<Tenant id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, home_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> first_name = "Billy"
=> "Billy"
>> last_name = "Jones"
=> "Jones"
>> tenant.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `tenants` (`created_at`, `first_name`, `home_id`, `last_name`,          `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-07-29 20:54:28', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-07-29 20:54:28')`  
Mysql2::Error: Column 'first_name' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `tenants` (`created_at`, `first_name`, `home_id`, `last_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-07-29 20:54:28', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-07-29 20:54:28')
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'first_name' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `tenants` (`created_at`, `first_name`, `home_id`, `last_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-07-29 20:54:28', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-07-29 20:54:28')

SO, I cannot determine the problem.  It says first_name cannot be null, obviously because I setup the database that way, but there is a value trying to go into database, even though I can return a value in Rails Console asking for first_name.....  Any advise?


Below are controller/model



***** TENANT CONTROLLER
class TenantsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        render('list')
    end

    def list
      @tenants = Tenant.order("tenants.last_name ASC")
    end

    def show
      @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @tenant = Tenant.new
    end

    def create
        @tenant = Tenant.new(params[:tenant])
        @tenant.save

        if @tenant.save
            flash[:notice] = "New Tenant was created successfully."
            redirect_to(:action => 'list')
        else
            render('new')
        end
    end

    def edit
      @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])

    end


    def update
        # find object using form parameters
        @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])

        #update the object
        if @tenant.update_attributes(params[:tenant])

            #if update succeeds redirect to
            flash[:notice] = "Tenant was updated successfully."
            redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @tenant.id)
            else
            render('edit')
        end

    end

    def delete
        @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])

    end

    def destroy
        @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
        @tenant.destroy

        flash[:notice] = "Tenant was destroyed successfully."
        redirect_to(:action => 'list' )

    end


end

***** TENANT MODEL
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :home_id
end
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `console` session you are never assigning `first_name` or `last_name` to the tenant record you instantiate via `Tenant.new` - so of course its empty. Try this;

```
tenant = Tenant.new
=> #<Tenant id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, home_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> tenant.first_name = "Billy"
=> "Billy"
>> tenant.last_name = "Jones"
=> "Jones"
>> tenant.save
```

You can streamline this by specifying the names on one line, and also use `create` which attempts an immediate save to the database:

```
tenant = Tenant.create(:first_name => "Billy", :last_name => "Jones")
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was overlooking something simple.  I got it right on five other entities than missed something so simple :)

Comment: user1543092, I think you should accept the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

when ruby exec

```
first_name = "Billy"
```

a new String var is created, you just forgot to specify your object:

```
tenant.first_name = "Billy"
```

Next time, to know the reason why the record was not saved, try:

```
puts tenant.errors.full_errors
```